# Is it possible to have two catches with the same Exception type from two different methods?

Tags: java, try-catch, inputmismatchexception

I'm new here and to programming, so sorry if this is too long. I'm sure there's a much easier way to do this, but I'd really like to see if this can get resolved. 
I'm working on a program that takes user input (double) and converts from Celsius to Fahrenheit (cToF) and vice versa (fToC) with constraints of 0 to 1000. I have a separate method for both cToF and fToC. 
I want to throw an exception for when the user doesn't input a double. I have catch (InputMismatchException cToF) and catch (InputMismatchException2 fToC) in the main that do different things. 
Also, I'm suspicious that the math is incorrect for fToC, I just haven't gotten to it yet.

I tried changing the name of InputMismatchException2 to InputMismatchException, but I get "exception has already been caught". 
I already have import java.util.*. 
I tried adding "throws Exception" at the beginning of the main method and both of the conversion methods. 
I'm not sure if the try-catch should be in the main, the individual methods, or both.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InputMismatchException, InputMismatchException2 {

    Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
    String unit = "n";
    boolean typo = false;
    double tempC = 0;
    double tempF = 0;

    try {
        start();//method to determine conversion type (F-C or C-F)

        if (typo == false) {

            do {//forever loop

                question(unit);

            }//end do loop
            while (typo == false);

        }//end if

        System.out.println("Thank you, goodbye!");

    }//end try

    catch (InputMismatchException cToFE) {//if a non-double is entered

        System.out.println("The value " + tempC + " is not within previously defined constraints.");
        System.out.println("Please enter a new value.");
        cToF(unit);

    }//end cToF catch

    catch (InputMismatchException2 fToCE) {//if a non-double is entered

        System.out.println("The value " + tempF + " is not within previously defined constraints.");
        System.out.println("Please enter a new value.");
        fToC(unit);

    }//end fToC catch

}//end main method

public static void cToF(String unit) throws InputMismatchException {

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Please enter a value from 0 to 1000.");//CONSTRAINTS: 0 <= temp <= 1000

    Scanner temp = new Scanner(System.in);
    double tempC = temp.nextDouble();

    if (0 <=  tempC && tempC <= 1000) {//if tempC is within constraints

        double tempF = (tempC * 1.8) + 32;//arithmetic with tempC == tempF

        System.out.println(tempC + " degrees Celsius is " + tempF + " degrees Fahrenheit");//print conversion

    }//end if
    else if (tempC < 0 || tempC > 1000) {//if tempC is NOT within constraints

        System.out.println("The value " + tempC + " is not within previously defined constraints.");
        System.out.println("Please enter a new value.");
        cToF(unit);

    }//end else if
    else {//if non-double entered

        //InputMismatchException cToFE = new InputMismatchException();
        throw new InputMismatchException();

    }//end else

}//end cToF method

public static void fToC(String unit) throws InputMismatchException2 {

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Please enter a value from 0 to 1000.");//CONSTRAINTS: 0 <= temp <= 1000

    Scanner temp = new Scanner(System.in);
    double tempF = temp.nextDouble();

    if (0 <=  tempF && tempF <= 1000) {//if tempF is within constraints

        double tempC = (32 - tempF) / 1.8;//arithmetic with tempF == tempC
        System.out.println(tempF + " degrees Fahrenheit is " + tempC + " degrees Celsius");//print conversion

    }//end if
    else if (tempF < 0 || tempF > 1000) {//if tempF is NOT within constraints

        System.out.println("The value " + tempF + " is not within previously defined constraints.");
        System.out.println("Please enter a new value.");
        fToC(unit);

    }//end else if
    else {//if non-double entered

        //InputMismatchException2 fToCE = new InputMismatchException2();
        throw new InputMismatchException2();

    }//end else

}//end fToC method
```

What I want: 
If the user types in a letter while in either method (fToC/cToF), print **The value** *[tempF/tempC respectively]* **is not within previously defined constraints. Please enter a new value.** 
Then recursively call either method to restart the temp input process.

What I'm getting (with current code):

```
$ javac Temperature.java
Temperature.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InputMismatchException, InputMismatchException2 {
                                                                          ^
  symbol:   class InputMismatchException2
  location: class Temperature
Temperature.java:125: error: cannot find symbol
    public static void fToC(String unit) throws InputMismatchException2 {
                                                ^
  symbol:   class InputMismatchException2
  location: class Temperature
Temperature.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
        catch (InputMismatchException2 fToCE) {//if a non-double is entered
               ^
  symbol:   class InputMismatchException2
  location: class Temperature
Temperature.java:151: error: cannot find symbol
            throw new InputMismatchException2();
                      ^
  symbol:   class InputMismatchException2
  location: class Temperature
4 errors
```

Comment: I call cToF/fToC in the start() method in the beginning. My understanding is that while it is in the cToF method and throws the exception, I can then have the catch print the error message and then call the method again, correct? That's why I was hoping that InputMismatchException vs InputMismatchException2 would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, [no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611982/catch-the-same-exception-twice), you cannot do this. Otherwise, it would be impossible to decide the correct catch statement to execute upon an exception being thrown.

Your error here is "error: cannot find symbol". According to the error traces, this means that the symbol `InputMismatchException2` cannot be found. Essentially, you will need to define a separate class `InputMismatchException2` (extending `InputMismatchException`) if you want to throw a `InputMismatchException2`. The reason that you could then run your code would be that you would literally be throwing and catching two different kinds of `InputMismatchException`, `InputMismatchException` and `InputMismatchException2`.

However! You will probably be much better off initializing an `InputMismatchException` [with a message](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)), and using its [getMessage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage()) method to extract the relevant information in the catch statement.

Looking closer at the code, it's [generally](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/189226) [not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/729412/5699679) [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/729404/5699679) to use exceptions as part of control flow.

Comment: Do I initialize it in the main method? Inside or outside the try? Because it's not a new method, right?

Comment: Initialize what? The exception? `throw new InputMismatchException("something didn't match!");` will do the trick.

Comment: When you do `catch(InputMismatchException ime) { ... }`, you want to use the value inside the exception as `ime.getMessage()`

Comment: @castiyeaux I've made a quick demo [here](https://repl.it/repls/GrizzledWidePatch). What will print is: `this will print` and `Something went wrong: something didn't match!`

Comment: I see! The last two comments helped a lot. Thank you so much!